# alternativa a copy de python en java

Tags: java

Me gustaría que no se me añadiera la lista a el mapa sin modificar y así poder añadiendo cada lista con la información de cada pollo sin que se modifiquen por la secuencia convencional de java, sé que en python hay un método llamado .copy que lo que hace es crear una copia de la lista, pero en java no sé que puedo usar, porfavor ayuda.

```
public class Pollitos328 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int casos;
        List<Integer>gallinero = new ArrayList();
        List pollito = new ArrayList();
        Map<Integer,List>pollitos = new HashMap();
        
        do{
            casos = sc.nextInt();
            for(int i = 3; i>0; i--)
                gallinero.add(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
            

            for(int numPollo = 0; numPollo<gallinero.get(2); numPollo++){
                for(int CantidadInfoPollo = 4; CantidadInfoPollo>0; CantidadInfoPollo--){
                    pollito.add(sc.next());
                }
                pollitos.put(numPollo, pollito);
                pollito.clear();
            }
            
            casos--;
        }while(casos>0);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Si no hay nada que lo sustituya, cómo podría resolverlo para guardar en un mapa distintas listas que voy introduciendo por teclado? Tendía que hacerlo con sublistas?

Comment: Si el comentario es sobre tu problema deberias ponerlo en la propia pregunta. Probaste usando el metodo copyOf()? es de la clase Arrays. Aca te dejo un articulo con varias maneras de copiar un array para asi preservar el original: https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-copy

Comment: A mi entender, tu código tiene dos problemas, el primer for, ni tiene las llaves, eso hace que el segundo este anidado en este, por otro lado, la linea "pollito.clear", vacia el array de salida, deberías quitarla.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Los for en java si tienen una sola sentencia no hace falta que tengan corchete ya que java hace solo la primera sentencia, y ya lo resolví, era simplemente creando una instancia del array como pone en el primer comentario, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Claro, pero eso es para arrays, yo estoy utilizando lista. La solución es creando una instancia de la lista cada vez que vuelve a entrar en el segundo for, que representa la información de cada pollo, muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Si @Jorge, lo se, solo que por alguna razón, a mi se me ejecutaban anidados, tuve que editar lo que publique, en realidad te preguntaba si deberían estar anidados, pero en fin, buenísimo que lo solucionaste, y gracias a ti!!

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres crear una copia, podrias usar esto:

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(oldList);
```